# Do I need higher pressure to create a ristretto?

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine

I want to make a ristretto. Besides grinding my coffee finer, do I need to increase the pressure of the steam, or should I leave it the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, a ristretto is an espresso shot pulled with half as much water. If you assume a normal shot is 30ml, the only practical difference in pulling a ristretto is to stop the extraction at 15ml.

The coffee grind, quantity and pull pressure should remain the same.

Regardless, if you feel as if the shot is taking too long, or coming out too fast, you could try adjusting the grind before adjusting the pressure, which should be trickier.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?  I encountered the term ristretto when Starbucks introduced their "flat white" drinks.  They say the espresso shots used in them are "ristretto", and I asked them to prepare me a double ristretto shot.  It turned out to be a larger volume and less intense than a normal double shot (doppio).

Comment: Well, it's hard to find good sources that define the exact specifications of each brew, as they vary from place to place.  Starbucks uses one of the more "American"  definition of the ristretto, since their normal espresso shot isn't the common 30ml.

Comment: A ristretto will **not** have the same grind as a standard espresso. The grind for ristretto will be finer. You need to pull a 1:1 ratio in roughly 30 seconds. This will require you to grind finer than you would for a standard espresso.